# MySQL query help needed - Counting timestamps grouped ranges

Tags: mysql

One would think this is simple, but has been kicking by butt all night. I have a log of sensor alerts and want to generate a table with simple counts of events that fall within 24hrs, 168hrs (1 wk), and 336hrs (2 wks) for each distinct sensor. I'm relatively new and self-taught at MySQL (running on GoDaddy) and have tried every variation of Count, Unique, Case, etc. that I found on the web. Help me Obi Wan...

Sample Data:

| Alert_timestamp | SensorID |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-18 21:41:59 | Sensor 1 |
| 2022-05-21 21:52:09 | Sensor 1 |
| 2022-05-24 05:00:39 | Sensor 2 |
| 2022-05-24 05:02:26 | Sensor 1 |
| 2022-05-24 18:37:34 | Sensor 4 |
| 2022-05-24 20:48:40 | Sensor 1 |
| 2022-05-26 21:20:54 | Sensor 2 |
| 2022-05-27 14:53:02 | Sensor 1 |
| 2022-06-01 19:06:14 | Sensor 4 |
| 2022-06-02 19:22:27 | Sensor 1 |
| ... | ... |

Desired Output (note: counts below don't correspond to table above). Even if a sensor has zero alerts (e.g. sensor exists in the table, but no events inside the date rage), i want to see those too.

```
       count of events that fall within these ranges
```

| Sensor | <24hrs | 24 to 168hrs | 168 to 336hrs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sensor 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Sensor 2 | 0 | 2 | 5 |
| Sensor 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Sensor 4 | 6 | 2 | 3 |

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.

```sql
SELECT SensorID, 
       SUM(    Alert_timestamp >  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL  24 HOUR)  `<24hrs`,
       SUM(    Alert_timestamp <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL  24 HOUR
           AND Alert_timestamp >  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 168 HOUR)  `24 to 168hrs`,
       SUM(    Alert_timestamp <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 168 HOUR
           AND Alert_timestamp >  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 336 HOUR)  `168 to 336hrs`       
FROM table 
WHERE Alert_timestamp > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 336 HOUR
GROUP BY SensorID
```

If the table contains the rows "in future" then add according conditions to the first aggregation and to WHERE.

The index by `(SensorID, Alert_timestamp)` will improve.

Comment: You're killing me, i was banging my head against the keyboard for hours.  That was fast and perfect! Just tested. THANK YOU! @Akina